# Clipping a background image within a scrollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview, background-image

I have a layout file with some contents in a ScrollView.  The last view has a large background image assigned with it in order to accommodate text of unknown length.
I wish this background image to at least extend to the bottom of the screen, but otherwise clip to the size of its associated text (so the user isn't presented with a large empty area of scrolling with nothing but a background image).

Here is one attempt:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Here's a random view with contents"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_text"
        android:hint="Here's\nan\nedit\ntext\nof\nunknown\nlength\nand\nsize" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_text_view">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/android_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/robot" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Here's some\nadditional text\nof\nunknown\nlength." />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The problem with this example is that the screen can be scrolled down a long ways because of the image.  I only want the screen to scroll if there is actual content, e.g. text, that extends past the bottom.

[image]

If I instead try to anchor the image view to the bottom of the text, I encounter the problem that the image gets clipped before the bottom of the screen, if there isn't much text.

Thus, the image should extend to the bottom of the screen, but only the text should cause scrolling.  If scrolling occurs, the image should scroll with it, revealing more of the image.

This one's been stumping me for a bit.  I'd love some ideas on how to do this, preferably without resorting to querying and setting view sizes from the activity code.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

Using a Frame Layout for the Imageview and the Textview at the bottom. Something like this.

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/edit_text_view">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/android_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="matrix"
                android:src="@drawable/background" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="Here's some\nadditional text\nof\nunknown\nlength.Here's some\nadditional text\nof\nunknown\nlength.Here's some\nadditional text\nof\nunknown\nlength.Here's some\nadditional text\nof\nunknown\nlength.Here's some\nadditional text\nof\nunknown\nlength.Here's some\nadditional text\nof\nunknown\nlength." />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work.

When there isn't much text in the last TextView, the screen still scrolls all the way to the bottom of the image.

I want the screen to only scroll based on the text, not the image (which is intended to be a background image and not content).